# Firebase: how to receive/add info to separate collection via JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

yeap, if read a title you can think that it is simple action via collection - but no -> in you we have a button "Add collection": not clear how to add this collection via code or how to receive these created collections.

Please take a look at the structure of BD in the attachment:

[image].

I can receive ID of a document, but not clear how to receive collection(s)/data of these collections. here i just receive the main ID, not "1" collection and his data:

```
  const listCollections = [];
  await db
  .collection(table)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      debugger
      const dataCollectionObject = doc.data();
      dataCollectionObject.id = doc.id;
      listCollections.push(dataCollectionObject);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a document, you need another query to inspect its sub-collections.
Also, I suggest not mixing *async/await* with *then*.

### A basic approach

```
const rootSnapshot = await db.collection(table).get();
const promises = rootSnapshot.docs.map(rootDoc => rootDoc.ref.collection("1").get());
const childrenDoc = await Promise.all(promises);
```

### Using collection group queries

see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)

```
const childrenDoc = await db.collectionGroup("1").get();
```

### If you do not know the sub-collection name

Bad luck! With Firestore you are required to know the name of your collections. You could for exemple store it in another data member:

```
document {
  someField: ...
  collectionIds: ["1", "2"] // store the sub-collection ids
  "1" // a sub-collection
  "2" // another sub-collection
}
```

Then when you retrieve such a document, inspect its data and loop on  `collectionIds` to query deeper.

Comment: thank you for your answer. One more question: in your example, you have hardcoded "1", but if I will have several collections and will not know their ID/Names - how to receive this data? thanks

Comment: sorry, according to my screen, you can see that I have created 1 collection -> "Tests", "Tests" has one document -> ID where I have added collection "1".

But I need to receive via JS all collections for this document (for ID "xyaQ....") - didn't find any solution to receive subcollection, could you help, please?

Comment: Have you tried the 3 approaches I suggested? What is the outcome? How does it differ from your expectations?